# Getting the text of the currently selected option in a select list

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract and assert on the text of the currently selected option in a drop down, and finding it harder to do than I expected.

The situation is as follows:

1. Open browser page with a drop down list on it
2. Assert that the currently selected item is X, the default
3. Click a button elsewhere that changes the value of the drop down
4. Assert that a part of the page based on the selected drop down has changed
5. Assert that the currently selected item in the list is now Y

The last step is the part that I can't get to work, and the second to last is what makes me believe that I don't have a timing issue, as other parts of the page have reacted to the altered drop down (this is in an Angular app, though I don't think that's adding to the problem).

The problem I think I'm having is that the `selected` attribute is set in the HTML and so is not being updated when the displayed value of the drop down is altered. So if I find all the `option` elements under the `select` in question, iterate over them and call `getAttribute("selected")` then the results of that don't change even though I can see that the displayed text in the drop down has been updated.

Attacking it from a slightly different angle, I tried to `getText` of the `select` itself, but that gives me back the text values of all the possible options, which makes sense.

The Java API has a `getFirstSelectedOption` which I was hoping to replicate, but it appears to do exactly what I'm describing above!

Comment: Is there a wait in between select value from drop down and get selected text?

Comment: You think I might be trying to do the assertion too quickly? I don't think that's the case (and there's a step I've missed in the list which I'll now add), but I'll give it a shot.